# Initializing private npm package generates super long dependency

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am a junior developer and got a question while packaging my react library.

When I run `npm init --scope="scope_name"` command, it generates super long dependencies in `package.json` automatically.

I'd like to know the reason why it is generated.

And also is it a requirement for deploying private npm pacakge?

I've researched for an hour and still could not find any good answer for this.

Thank you!

P.S: This is the dependency that is generated by npm automatically.

```
"dependencies": {
    "acorn-globals": "^4.3.4",
    "acorn": "^6.4.0",
    "abab": "^2.0.3",
    "accepts": "^1.3.7",
    "acorn-walk": "^6.2.0",
    "address": "^1.1.2",
    "ajv": "^6.12.0",
    "airbnb-js-shims": "^2.2.1",
    "aggregate-error": "^3.0.1",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.4.1",
    "ajv-errors": "^1.0.1",
    "ansi-align": "^3.0.0",
    "ansi-colors": "^3.2.4",
    "ansi-regex": "^2.1.1",
    "ansi-html": "^0.0.7",
    "ansi-escapes": "^3.2.0",
    "alphanum-sort": "^1.0.2",
    "ansi-to-html": "^0.6.14",
    "ansi-styles": "^3.2.1",
    "app-root-dir": "^1.0.2",
    "anymatch": "^2.0.0",
    "aproba": "^1.2.0",
    "are-we-there-yet": "^1.1.5",
    "arr-union": "^3.1.0",
    "argparse": "^1.0.10",
    "arr-flatten": "^1.1.0",
    "arr-diff": "^4.0.0",
    "array-equal": "^1.0.0",
    "array-includes": "^3.1.1",
    "array-flatten": "^1.1.1",
    "array-union": "^1.0.2",
    "array-unique": "^0.3.2",
    "array-uniq": "^1.0.3",
    "array.prototype.flat": "^1.2.3",
    "array.prototype.flatmap": "^1.2.3",
    "array.prototype.map": "^1.0.2",
    "asap": "^2.0.6",
    "asn1": "^0.2.4",
    "arrify": "^1.0.1",
    "asn1.js": "^4.10.1",
    "abbrev": "^1.1.1",
    "assert-plus": "^1.0.0",
    "ast-types": "^0.11.3",
    "assign-symbols": "^1.0.0",
    "async-limiter": "^1.0.1",
    "async-each": "^1.0.3",
    "asynckit": "^0.4.0",
    "aws4": "^1.9.1",
    "atob": "^2.1.2",
    "aws-sign2": "^0.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-helper-bindify-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-code-frame": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-helper-evaluate-path": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-helper-explode-class": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-helper-explode-assignable-expression": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-helper-flip-expressions": "^0.4.3",
    "babel-helper-function-name": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-helper-get-function-arity": "^6.24.1",
    "async-retry": "^1.3.1",
    "babel-helper-is-nodes-equiv": "^0.0.1",
    "babel-helper-is-void-0": "^0.4.3",
    "babel-helper-remove-or-void": "^0.4.3",
    "babel-helper-to-multiple-sequence-expressions": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-helper-mark-eval-scopes": "^0.4.3",
    "babel-helper-remap-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-messages": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-react-displayname": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-emotion": "^10.0.29",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^2.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-minify-builtins": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-minify-constant-folding": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-minify-flip-comparisons": "^0.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-minify-guarded-expressions": "^0.4.4",
    "babel-plugin-minify-dead-code-elimination": "^0.5.1",
    "babel-plugin-minify-mangle-names": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-minify-infinity": "^0.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-minify-numeric-literals": "^0.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-minify-replace": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-minify-simplify": "^0.5.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-docgen": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.6",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-generators": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-decorators": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-do-expressions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-exponentiation-operator": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-export-extensions": "^6.13.0",
    "assert": "^1.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-class-constructor-call": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-function-bind": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-minify-type-constructors": "^0.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-constructor-call": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-do-expressions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-function-bind": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-consecutive-adds": "^0.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-merge-sibling-variables": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-minify-booleans": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-property-literals": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-debugger": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-undefined": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-undefined-to-void": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-simplify-comparison-operators": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-template": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-traverse": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "^6.26.0",
    "babylon": "^6.18.0",
    "balanced-match": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regexp-constructors": "^0.4.3",
    "base": "^0.11.2",
    "base64-js": "^1.3.1",
    "batch-processor": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-member-expression-literals": "^6.9.4",
    "bindings": "^1.5.0",
    "bcrypt-pbkdf": "^1.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "binary-extensions": "^1.13.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas": "^6.22.0",
    "bn.js": "^4.11.8",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "boolbase": "^1.0.0",
    "brace-expansion": "^1.1.11",
    "braces": "^2.3.2",
    "boxen": "^4.2.0",
    "brorand": "^1.1.0",
    "browserify-aes": "^1.2.0",
    "browser-process-hrtime": "^0.1.3",
    "browserify-cipher": "^1.0.1",
    "browserify-rsa": "^4.0.1",
    "browserify-des": "^1.0.2",
    "browserify-sign": "^4.0.4",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.9.1",
    "buffer": "^4.9.2",
    "buffer-from": "^1.1.1",
    "buffer-xor": "^1.0.3",
    "builtin-status-codes": "^3.0.0",
    "builtin-modules": "^3.1.0",
    "bytes": "^3.1.0",
    "cacache": "^12.0.3",
    "call-me-maybe": "^1.0.1",
    "cache-base": "^1.0.1",
    "caller-callsite": "^2.0.0",
    "caller-path": "^2.0.0",
    "camel-case": "^4.1.1",
    "callsites": "^2.0.0",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "can-use-dom": "^0.1.0",
    "caniuse-api": "^3.0.0",
    "camelize": "^1.0.0",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001031",
    "caseless": "^0.12.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "character-entities": "^1.2.4",
    "character-reference-invalid": "^1.1.4",
    "character-entities-legacy": "^1.1.4",
    "chokidar": "^2.1.8",
    "chownr": "^1.1.4",
    "cipher-base": "^1.0.4",
    "chrome-trace-event": "^1.0.2",
    "clean-css": "^4.2.3",
    "class-utils": "^0.3.6",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "clean-stack": "^2.2.0",
    "cli-table3": "^0.5.1",
    "cli-boxes": "^2.2.0",
    "cli-cursor": "^2.1.0",
    "cli-width": "^2.2.0",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "clone-deep": "^0.2.4",
    "cliui": "^3.2.0",
    "coa": "^2.0.2",
    "collection-visit": "^1.0.0",
    "color": "^3.1.2",
    "code-point-at": "^1.1.0",
    "color-convert": "^1.9.3",
    "color-name": "^1.1.4",
    "combined-stream": "^1.0.8",
    "color-string": "^1.5.3",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "comma-separated-tokens": "^1.0.8",
    "commander": "^2.20.3",
    "commondir": "^1.0.1",
    "concat-map": "^0.0.1",
    "concat-with-sourcemaps": "^1.1.0",
    "component-emitter": "^1.3.0",
    "concat-stream": "^1.6.2",
    "console-browserify": "^1.2.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "console-control-strings": "^1.1.0",
    "chardet": "^0.7.0",
    "convert-source-map": "^1.7.0",
    "content-type": "^1.0.4",
    "content-disposition": "^0.5.3",
    "copy-concurrently": "^1.0.5",
    "cookie-signature": "^1.0.6",
    "cookie": "^0.4.0",
    "copy-descriptor": "^0.1.1",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
    "core-js-pure": "^3.6.4",
    "corejs-upgrade-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "cosmiconfig": "^5.2.1",
    "create-hash": "^1.2.0",
    "create-react-context": "^0.3.0",
    "create-ecdh": "^4.0.3",
    "create-hmac": "^1.1.7",
    "cross-spawn": "^6.0.5",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "css-declaration-sorter": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "css-color-keywords": "^1.0.0",
    "css-modules-loader-core": "^1.1.0",
    "css-color-names": "^0.0.4",
    "css-to-react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "css-select": "^2.1.0",
    "css-select-base-adapter": "^0.1.1",
    "css-tree": "^1.0.0-alpha.37",
    "css-selector-tokenizer": "^0.7.1",
    "core-js-compat": "^3.6.4",
    "cssnano-preset-default": "^4.0.7",
    "cssesc": "^3.0.0",
    "css-what": "^3.2.1",
    "cssnano-util-raw-cache": "^4.0.1",
    "cssnano-util-same-parent": "^4.0.1",
    "cssnano-util-get-match": "^4.0.0",
    "cssnano-util-get-arguments": "^4.0.0",
    "csso": "^4.0.2",
    "cssstyle": "^1.4.0",
    "csstype": "^2.6.9",
    "cyclist": "^1.0.1",
    "cssom": "^0.3.8",
    "dashdash": "^1.14.1",
    "data-urls": "^1.1.0",
    "decamelize": "^1.2.0",
    "debug": "^2.6.9",
    "decode-uri-component": "^0.2.0",
    "deep-equal": "^1.1.1",
    "deep-extend": "^0.6.0",
    "deep-is": "^0.1.3",
    "deep-object-diff": "^1.1.0",
    "define-properties": "^1.1.3",
    "define-property": "^0.2.5",
    "delegates": "^1.0.0",
    "delegate": "^3.2.0",
    "delayed-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "des.js": "^1.0.1",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "denodeify": "^1.2.1",
    "depd": "^1.1.2",
    "detect-node": "^2.0.4",
    "destroy": "^1.0.4",
    "detect-indent": "^5.0.0",
    "detect-libc": "^1.0.3",
    "detect-port": "^1.3.0",
    "detect-port-alt": "^1.1.6",
    "diff": "^4.0.2",
    "doctrine": "^3.0.0",
    "dom-converter": "^0.2.0",
    "diffie-hellman": "^5.0.3",
    "dir-glob": "^2.2.2",
    "dom-helpers": "^3.4.0",
    "dom-serializer": "^0.2.2",
    "dom-walk": "^0.1.1",
    "domain-browser": "^1.2.0",
    "domexception": "^1.0.1",
    "domelementtype": "^1.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "domhandler": "^2.4.2",
    "dot-case": "^3.0.3",
    "domutils": "^1.7.0",
    "dot-prop": "^5.2.0",
    "dotenv-defaults": "^1.1.1",
    "dotenv-expand": "^5.1.0",
    "duplexer": "^0.1.1",
    "duplexify": "^3.7.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "ee-first": "^1.1.1",
    "ecc-jsbn": "^0.1.2",
    "ejs": "^2.7.4",
    "electron-to-chromium": "^1.3.364",
    "element-resize-detector": "^1.2.1",
    "elliptic": "^6.5.2",
    "emoji-regex": "^8.0.0",
    "emotion-theming": "^10.0.27",
    "emojis-list": "^3.0.0",
    "encodeurl": "^1.0.2",
    "entities": "^1.1.2",
    "end-of-stream": "^1.4.4",
    "encoding": "^0.1.12",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^4.1.1",
    "env-ci": "^2.6.0",
    "errno": "^0.1.7",
    "error-ex": "^1.3.2",
    "es-abstract": "^1.17.4",
    "es-array-method-boxes-properly": "^1.0.0",
    "es-to-primitive": "^1.2.1",
    "es-get-iterator": "^1.1.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.13",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.5",
    "escape-html": "^1.0.3",
    "big.js": "^5.2.2",
    "eslint-scope": "^4.0.3",
    "escodegen": "^1.14.1",
    "estraverse": "^4.3.0",
    "esprima": "^4.0.1",
    "estree-walker": "^0.6.1",
    "esrecurse": "^4.2.1",
    "etag": "^1.8.1",
    "esutils": "^2.0.3",
    "eventsource": "^1.0.7",
    "evp_bytestokey": "^1.0.3",
    "events": "^3.1.0",
    "eventemitter3": "^4.0.0",
    "expand-brackets": "^2.1.4",
    "extend-shallow": "^2.0.1",
    "execa": "^1.0.0",
    "extend": "^3.0.2",
    "extglob": "^2.0.4",
    "external-editor": "^3.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^2.0.1",
    "fast-glob": "^2.2.7",
    "extsprintf": "^1.3.0",
    "fast-json-parse": "^1.0.3",
    "fake-tag": "^1.0.1",
    "fast-levenshtein": "^2.0.6",
    "fast-safe-stringify": "^1.2.3",
    "fastparse": "^1.1.2",
    "fault": "^1.0.4",
    "fast-json-stable-stringify": "^2.1.0",
    "faye-websocket": "^0.11.3",
    "fbjs": "^0.8.17",
    "figgy-pudding": "^3.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "figures": "^2.0.0",
    "filesize": "^3.6.1",
    "finalhandler": "^1.1.2",
    "file-uri-to-path": "^1.0.0",
    "file-system-cache": "^1.0.5",
    "flatstr": "^1.0.12",
    "fill-range": "^4.0.0",
    "find-cache-dir": "^2.1.0",
    "flush-write-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "find-up": "^3.0.0",
    "find-root": "^1.1.0",
    "focus-lock": "^0.6.6",
    "follow-redirects": "^1.5.10",
    "for-own": "^0.1.5",
    "forever-agent": "^0.6.1",
    "for-in": "^1.0.2",
    "format": "^0.2.2",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "fresh": "^0.5.2",
    "form-data": "^2.3.3",
    "forwarded": "^0.1.2",
    "fragment-cache": "^0.2.1",
    "fs-write-stream-atomic": "^1.0.10",
    "from2": "^2.3.0",
    "fs-minipass": "^2.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "fsevents": "^1.2.11",
    "function.prototype.name": "^1.1.2",
    "fs.realpath": "^1.0.0",
    "fuse.js": "^3.4.6",
    "functions-have-names": "^1.2.1",
    "function-bind": "^1.1.1",
    "gauge": "^2.7.4",
    "generic-names": "^2.0.1",
    "gensync": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "get-caller-file": "^1.0.3",
    "get-value": "^2.0.6",
    "getpass": "^0.1.7",
    "get-stream": "^4.1.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "glob-base": "^0.3.0",
    "glob-parent": "^3.1.0",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "glob-to-regexp": "^0.3.0",
    "global-modules": "^2.0.0",
    "global-prefix": "^3.0.0",
    "globalthis": "^1.0.1",
    "globals": "^11.12.0",
    "gud": "^1.0.0",
    "globby": "^9.2.0",
    "har-schema": "^2.0.0",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.3",
    "gzip-size": "^5.1.1",
    "good-listener": "^1.2.2",
    "har-validator": "^5.1.3",
    "has-ansi": "^2.0.0",
    "has": "^1.0.3",
    "has-unicode": "^2.0.1",
    "has-flag": "^3.0.0",
    "has-value": "^1.0.0",
    "has-symbols": "^1.0.1",
    "has-yarn": "^2.1.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.5",
    "hash.js": "^1.1.7",
    "hash-base": "^3.0.4",
    "hast-util-parse-selector": "^2.2.4",
    "hastscript": "^5.1.2",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "hex-color-regex": "^1.1.0",
    "hmac-drbg": "^1.0.1",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2",
    "highlight.js": "^9.13.1",
    "html-comment-regex": "^1.1.2",
    "hsl-regex": "^1.0.0",
    "hosted-git-info": "^2.8.8",
    "html-entities": "^1.2.1",
    "hsla-regex": "^1.0.0",
    "html-encoding-sniffer": "^1.0.2",
    "html-minifier-terser": "^5.0.4",
    "htmlparser2": "^3.10.1",
    "http-parser-js": "^0.4.10",
    "http-signature": "^1.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.11",
    "http-errors": "^1.7.2",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "icss-utils": "^4.1.1",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.4.24",
    "icss-replace-symbols": "^1.1.0",
    "iferr": "^0.1.5",
    "ieee754": "^1.1.13",
    "ignore": "^4.0.6",
    "has-values": "^1.0.0",
    "import-cwd": "^2.1.0",
    "immer": "^1.10.0",
    "import-fresh": "^2.0.0",
    "ignore-walk": "^3.0.3",
    "indent-string": "^4.0.0",
    "indexes-of": "^1.0.1",
    "imurmurhash": "^0.1.4",
    "import-from": "^2.1.0",
    "infer-owner": "^1.0.4",
    "ini": "^1.3.5",
    "inherits": "^2.0.4",
    "inquirer": "^6.5.0",
    "interpret": "^2.0.0",
    "invert-kv": "^1.0.0",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "internal-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "is-accessor-descriptor": "^1.0.0",
    "ipaddr.js": "^1.9.1",
    "ip": "^1.1.5",
    "is-alphabetical": "^1.0.4",
    "is-absolute-url": "^2.1.0",
    "is-alphanumerical": "^1.0.4",
    "is-binary-path": "^1.0.1",
    "is-callable": "^1.1.5",
    "is-arrayish": "^0.2.1",
    "is-buffer": "^1.1.6",
    "is-arguments": "^1.0.4",
    "is-data-descriptor": "^1.0.0",
    "is-color-stop": "^1.1.0",
    "is-decimal": "^1.0.4",
    "is-descriptor": "^1.0.2",
    "is-date-object": "^1.0.2",
    "is-directory": "^0.3.1",
    "is-docker": "^2.0.0",
    "is-dom": "^1.1.0",
    "is-extendable": "^0.1.1",
    "is-fullwidth-code-point": "^2.0.0",
    "is-function": "^1.0.1",
    "is-glob": "^2.0.1",
    "is-extglob": "^2.1.1",
    "is-map": "^2.0.1",
    "is-number": "^3.0.0",
    "is-hexadecimal": "^1.0.4",
    "is-module": "^1.0.0",
    "is-object": "^1.0.1",
    "is-plain-obj": "^1.1.0",
    "is-obj": "^2.0.0",
    "is-promise": "^2.1.0",
    "is-plain-object": "^2.0.4",
    "is-reference": "^1.1.4",
    "is-regex": "^1.0.5",
    "is-set": "^2.0.1",
    "is-string": "^1.0.5",
    "is-resolvable": "^1.1.0",
    "is-root": "^2.1.0",
    "is-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "is-symbol": "^1.0.3",
    "is-svg": "^3.0.0",
    "is-typedarray": "^1.0.0",
    "is-utf8": "^0.2.1",
    "is-window": "^1.0.2",
    "is-windows": "^1.0.2",
    "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
    "isexe": "^2.0.0",
    "isarray": "^1.0.0",
    "isobject": "^3.0.1",
    "iterate-iterator": "^1.0.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "java-properties": "^0.2.10",
    "isstream": "^0.1.2",
    "jest-worker": "^25.1.0",
    "js-tokens": "^4.0.0",
    "iterate-value": "^1.0.2",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.1",
    "jsbn": "^0.1.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.12.0",
    "json-parse-better-errors": "^1.0.2",
    "json-schema": "^0.2.3",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "jsesc": "^0.5.0",
    "json-schema-traverse": "^0.4.1",
    "json3": "^3.3.3",
    "json5": "^2.1.1",
    "jsonfile": "^4.0.0",
    "jsprim": "^1.4.1",
    "kind-of": "^3.2.2",
    "klaw": "^1.3.1",
    "lazy-cache": "^1.0.4",
    "lazy-universal-dotenv": "^3.0.1",
    "lcid": "^1.0.0",
    "left-pad": "^1.3.0",
    "levenary": "^1.1.1",
    "leven": "^3.1.0",
    "levn": "^0.3.0",
    "lines-and-columns": "^1.1.6",
    "loader-utils": "^1.4.0",
    "load-json-file": "^1.1.0",
    "loader-runner": "^2.4.0",
    "locate-path": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "lodash.camelcase": "^4.3.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "lodash.sortby": "^4.7.0",
    "lowlight": "^1.11.0",
    "lodash.uniq": "^4.5.0",
    "loose-envify": "^1.4.0",
    "lru-cache": "^5.1.1",
    "lower-case": "^2.0.1",
    "magic-string": "^0.25.6",
    "mamacro": "^0.0.3",
    "make-dir": "^2.1.0",
    "map-cache": "^0.2.2",
    "map-or-similar": "^1.5.0",
    "map-visit": "^1.0.0",
    "markdown-to-jsx": "^6.11.0",
    "marksy": "^8.0.0",
    "marked": "^0.3.19",
    "material-colors": "^1.2.6",
    "mdn-data": "^2.0.4",
    "md5.js": "^1.3.5",
    "memoize-one": "^5.1.1",
    "media-typer": "^0.3.0",
    "memoizerific": "^1.11.3",
    "memory-fs": "^0.4.1",
    "merge-deep": "^3.0.2",
    "merge-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "merge-descriptors": "^1.0.1",
    "merge2": "^1.3.0",
    "methods": "^1.1.2",
    "microevent.ts": "^0.1.1",
    "micromatch": "^3.1.10",
    "mimic-fn": "^1.2.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.26",
    "miller-rabin": "^4.0.1",
    "mime": "^2.4.4",
    "mime-db": "^1.43.0",
    "min-indent": "^1.0.0",
    "min-document": "^2.19.0",
    "minimalistic-assert": "^1.0.1",
    "inflight": "^1.0.6",
    "minimalistic-crypto-utils": "^1.0.1",
    "minipass": "^3.1.1",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "minipass-pipeline": "^1.2.2",
    "minipass-flush": "^1.0.5",
    "minizlib": "^1.3.3",
    "minipass-collect": "^1.0.2",
    "mississippi": "^3.0.0",
    "mixin-object": "^2.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "ms": "^2.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mixin-deep": "^1.3.2",
    "move-concurrently": "^1.0.1",
    "nan": "^2.14.0",
    "mute-stream": "^0.0.7",
    "nanomatch": "^1.2.13",
    "needle": "^2.3.3",
    "negotiator": "^0.6.2",
    "nested-object-assign": "^1.0.3",
    "neo-async": "^2.6.1",
    "no-case": "^3.0.3",
    "nice-try": "^1.0.5",
    "node-ask": "^1.0.1",
  .... }
```